# Get row positions with mismatched values after dataframe concatenation in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two dataframes and I would like to do a detailed comparison between them. This means that I want to match cell values for each column (and all its rows) from df_one with df_two. Currently, I'm concatenating them into a third dataframe and would like to get the row positions where there is a mismatch in each column. For example:

df_one looks like this -

[image]

df_two looks like this -

[image]

Now I'm concatenating them like this -

```
df_one.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_two.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_concat = pd.concat([df_one,df_two],axis=0).fillna('---')
```

Output after concatenating -

[image]

Here's what I want to get from all this -

A) I want to do a row-by-row comparison within each column between the two dataframes (after concatenation) and get row positions where they differ.

```
SAMPLE OUTPUT -- (When comparing column Month)

Row positions with mismatch - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 

SAMPLE OUTPUT -- (When comparing column Year)

No mismatch found between columns Year in both datasets

SAMPLE OUTPUT -- (When comparing column Day)

No mismatch found between columns Day in both datasets

SAMPLE OUTPUT -- (When comparing column Country)

Row positions with mismatch - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

B) Also, is there a way to add a tag or something to distinguish the dataframes from one another in the concatenated form?

Note: Another way to do this (without concat) would be to check if column Day from df_one exists in df_two and then iterate over all rows -- and then do this essentially for all columns in df_1. But I think that would be very inefficient if there are 200 columns in the df_one and 250 columns in df_two.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at using keys parameter in pd.concat.   And I don't understand what you want with A.  Can you given an example output?

Comment: Also it would be easier to do any sort of comparison if you concat on axis 1

Comment: @ScottBoston Added sample output

Comment: @Vaishali - if I concat with axis=1, then columns with same name get created, so is there a way to compare column Month (coming from df_one) with column Month (coming from df_two) - since both column names are the same?